# vb.net Twitter GET oauth/authorize example

Tags: vb.net, twitter, authorize

I tried many ways to authorize my vb.net project on my twitter account, but I couldn't do it. My last try is;

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO

Public Class authRequest
    Private oauth_consumer_key As String
    Private consumer_secret As String
    Private oauth_token As String
    Private oauth_token_secret As String
    Private oauth_timestamp As String 'The number of seconds since the Unix epoch at the point the request is generated 
    Private oauth_nonce As String 'An hash identifing the request

    'We are going to invoke the search API 
    Private requestUrl As String = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
    Private requestMethod As String = "GET"
    Private oauth_version As String = "1.0"
    Private oauth_signature_method As String = "HMAC-SHA1"

    Public Sub New(ByVal oauth_consumer_key_in As String, ByVal consumer_secret_in As String, ByVal oauth_token_in As String, ByVal oauth_token_secret_in As String)
        oauth_consumer_key = oauth_consumer_key_in
        consumer_secret = consumer_secret_in
        oauth_token = oauth_token_in
        oauth_token_secret = oauth_token_secret_in
    End Sub

    Private Function setNounce() As String
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(New ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()))
    End Function

    Private Function setTimeStamp() As String
        Dim timeSpan As TimeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
        Return Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString()
    End Function

    Private Function percEncode(ByVal StringToEncode As String) As String
        Dim utf8Encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(True)
        Dim encodedString() As Byte
        encodedString = utf8Encoding.GetBytes(StringToEncode)
        StringToEncode = utf8Encoding.GetString(encodedString)
        Return System.Uri.EscapeDataString(StringToEncode)
    End Function

    Public Function getSignature(ByVal consumer_key_in As String, ByVal oauth_nonce_in As String, ByVal oauth_timestamp_in As String, ByVal oauth_token_in As String, ByVal consumer_secret_in As String, ByVal oauth_token_Secret_in As String, ByVal query As String) As String
        Dim myKey As String = percEncode(consumer_secret_in) + "&" + percEncode(oauth_token_Secret_in)
        Dim percURL = percEncode(requestUrl)
        Dim ris As String = ""
        Dim signature_base As String = ""
        Dim mypar As String = createAuthParam(consumer_key_in, oauth_nonce_in, oauth_timestamp_in, oauth_token_in, query)
        signature_base = requestMethod & "&" & percURL & "&" & percEncode(mypar)
        ris = HashString(signature_base, myKey)
        Return ris
    End Function

    Public Function HashString(ByVal StringToHash As String, ByVal Key As String) As String
        Dim oauth_signature As String
        Dim hasher As HMACSHA1 = New HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key))
        Using hasher
            oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(StringToHash)))
        End Using
        Return oauth_signature
    End Function

    Public Function createAuthParam(ByVal consumer_key_in As String, ByVal nonce_in As String, ByVal oauth_timestamp_in As String, ByVal oauth_token_in As String, ByVal query As String) As String
        Dim paramString As String = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&{6}"
        Dim authString As String = String.Format(paramString, percEncode(consumer_key_in), percEncode(nonce_in), oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp_in, oauth_token_in, oauth_version, reqParam(query))
        Return authString
    End Function

    Public Function reqParam(ByVal statusInput As String) As String
        Return "oauth_token=" & statusInput
    End Function

    Public Function makeRequest(ByVal query As String)
        Dim requestResult As String = ""
        oauth_nonce = setNounce()
        oauth_timestamp = setTimeStamp()
        Dim oauth_signature As String = getSignature(oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_timestamp, oauth_token, consumer_secret, oauth_token_secret, query)


        'Set the authorization header
        Dim headerFormat As String = "OAuth oauth_nonce=""{0}"", oauth_signature_method=""{1}"", oauth_timestamp=""{2}"", oauth_consumer_key=""{3}"", oauth_token=""{4}"", oauth_signature=""{5}"", oauth_version=""{6}"""
        Dim authHeader As String = String.Format(headerFormat, Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version))


        'set the request
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        Dim streamReader As System.IO.StreamReader
        Dim encode As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
        request = HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl & "?" & "oauth_token=" & oauth_token)
        request.Timeout = -1
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader)

        Try
            response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            streamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encode)
            requestResult = streamReader.ReadLine()
            request.Abort()
            streamReader.Close()
            streamReader = Nothing
            response.Close()
            response = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try

        Return requestResult
    End Function
End Class
```

But this codes return "403 Forbidden". Can anyone give me an example for twitter authorize in vb.net? I'm really tired.

Comment: Answer can be with LinqToTwitter library, I can't use this library, too.

Comment: I am not sure you are going about it right.  If you want your app to access your account you need to use the ["3-legged OAuth"](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/3-legged-authorization) method they document which involves getting a PIN first, then using it to get an authorization token, the token can then be used to access your account for a time.